# How to make posts with youtube on meteorjs?

Tags: javascript, iframe, meteor, youtube-api

Im trying to make posts with youtube video. Every post has a link on youtube video, just like that:

```
{
   title: "Some video",
   link: "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfWnITmT1Ws"
}
```

and template post is

```
<template name="post">
  <h1>{{title}}</h1>
  <iframe width="420" height="315" 
   src="{{link}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</template>
```

But it doesn't work. The error is

```
Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpEgXOgRQ8w'
in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

Somebody met it? What should i do?

Answer (score 2):

How about using the Youtube API for displaying videos ? You're actually trying to integrate the Youtube Video using an iframe to the video page, whereas youtube provides embed code :

`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/{{video_id link}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>`

Note you will have to register a template helper video_id that takes as argument the video link and returns the video id (in bold here : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=**gpEgXOgRQ8w**)

Comment: Thank you, i took id form the link, and put it in what you said, but it still doesn't work

Comment: Did you register the `video_id` helper ? Check the console output.

Comment: Check out my code here : http://meteorpad.com/pad/NzPH5k4hnvNm5gtyz/Youtube for an example. :)